# Script to Format and Mount all available instance store devices

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

Amazon [provides instance store](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html) for EC2 instances. If you use your own AMI, these are not formatted or mounted automatically for you. You need to manually format and mount them.

The available devices are [listed here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html#InstanceStoreDeviceNames) and vary based on type of instance. For example an m1.small will have different available instance store devices than c1.xlarge.

I'm looking for a script which

1. Detects what the instance type is. Perhaps by using 
   `curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-type`
2. Formats and mounts all devices which are available for that instance type but have not yet been formatted/mounted.

Possible? Done it? Have it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, here is what I built for this.

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script formats and mounts all available Instance Store devices

##### Variables
devices=( )

##### Functions

function add_device
{
    devices=( "${devices[@]}" $1 )
}

function check_device
{
    if [ -e /dev/$1 ]; then
        add_device $1
    fi
}

function check_devices
{
    check_device sda2
    check_device sda3
    check_device sdb
    check_device sdc
    check_device sdd
    check_device sde
}

function print_devices
{
    for device in "${devices[@]}"
    do
        echo Found device $device
    done
}

function do_mount
{
    echo Mounting device $1 on $2
fdisk $1 << EOF
n
p
1



w
EOF
# format!
mkfs -t xfs -f $1

mkdir $2
mount $1 $2

echo "$1   $2      xfs     defaults          0 0" >> /etc/fstab

}

function mount_devices
{
    for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#devices[@]} ; i++ ))
    do
        mountTarget=/mnt
        if [ $i -gt 0 ]; then
            mountTarget=/mnt$(($i+1))
        fi
        do_mount /dev/${devices[$i]} $mountTarget
    done
}


##### Main

check_devices
print_devices
mount_devices
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
#SETUP RAID0
checkAllDevices()
{
    devicemount=/ephemeral
    logicalname=/dev/md0
    deviceslist=( '/dev/xvdb' '/dev/xvdc' '/dev/xvdd' '/dev/xvde' )
    for device in ${deviceslist[@]}; do
        if ([ -b $device ]) then
            aDevices=( "${aDevices[@]}" $device )
        fi
    done
    if [ "${#aDevices[@]}" -gt '1' ];then
        yes | mdadm --create $logicalname --level=0 -c256 --raid-devices=${#aDevices[@]} ${aDevices[@]}
        echo \'DEVICE ${aDevices[@]}\' > /etc/mdadm.conf
        mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm.conf
        blockdev --setra 65536 $logicalname
        mkfs.xfs -f $logicalname > /dev/null
        mkdir -p $devicemount
        mount -t xfs -o noatime $logicalname $devicemount
        if [ ! -f /etc/fstab.backup ]; then
            cp -rP /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.backup
            echo "$logicalname $devicemount    xfs  defaults  0 0" >> /etc/fstab
        fi        
    else
        echo "Required more than one devices"
    fi
}

#MAIN FUNCTION 
aDevices=()
checkAllDevices
```